# Surprising behavior when OptionsPattern is part of a larger pattern

Tags: pattern-matching

Say we have a pattern defined as:

```
pattern = {foo[OptionsPattern[]] ...};
```

We can then use `MatchQ` to see whether an expression matches `pattern`, and some simple results work as I expect:

```
In[2]:= MatchQ[{foo[a -> b]}, pattern]
Out[2]= True

In[3]:= MatchQ[{foo[]}, pattern]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= MatchQ[{foo[a -> b], foo[a -> b]}, pattern]
Out[4]= True
```

However, other things don't work as I'd expect:

```
In[5]:= MatchQ[{foo[a -> b], foo[]}, pattern]
Out[5]= False

In[6]:= MatchQ[{foo[a -> b], foo[a -> c]}, pattern]
Out[6]= False
```

As far as I can tell, different occurrences of `OptionsPattern[]` all have to match the same thing for the pattern as a whole to match, much like named patterns, where `{x_, x_}` will match `{a, a}`, but not `{a, b}`. However, there doesn't seem to be anything about this in the documentation, and it's hard to be certain that's what's going on.

FWIW, there's an easy workaround, where you use

```
pattern = {foo[___?OptionQ]...}
```

Answer (score 6):

We can see that unlike `{x_, x_}` two occurrences of `OptionsPattern[]` do not need to have the same content:

```
pattern = {foo[OptionsPattern[]], foo[OptionsPattern[]]};

MatchQ[{foo[a -> b], foo[a -> c]}, pattern]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

We can also see that [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) can in some cases work with `OptionsPattern[]`:

```
MatchQ[
  {foo[a -> b], foo[a -> c]},
  {_[OptionsPattern[]] ..}
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
MatchQ[
  {foo[a -> b], foo[]},
  {_[OptionsPattern[]] ..}
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Curiously this also works:

```
MatchQ[
 {foo[a -> b], foo[a -> c]},
 {foo[OptionsPattern[]], foo[OptionsPattern[]] ..}
]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

I shall continue to explore this but it might be a bug in pattern matcher, or at least an edge case since this isn't the normal use of `OptionsPattern`.

Comment: We also believe this might be a bug, and are investigating.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you!